# public_path() returning results with backslash instead of forward slash

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am writing,

```
<?php echo public_path();?>
```

It returns results with backlashes instead of forward slashes. I expected forward slashes.

Comment: What is your `OS`?

Comment: Windows is my OS

Comment: What's the problem? What do you want resolved? It's backslashes on Windows, slashes on Linux.

Comment: Its not opening the files whose path I am giving using the function.

Comment: `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` (pre-defined constant) returns the slash depending on `OS`. There will be no problem.

Comment: please be more specific. public_path() returns DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR depend on os. update your question and give us your view and the way you want to view your file. is it an image or just a file?

Comment: @devk  The directory separators in Windows are both slashes or backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-public-path) uses `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` which depends on your OS. To change it to backslashes, you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace('\\', '/', public_path())
```

**Update**

For loading assets, use the [`assets()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-asset) helper.

Comment: Why it's necessary to replace it?

Comment: Its not opening the assets I am giving the path of.

Comment: @FahadUddin for loading assets, use the `asset()` helper.

Comment: @TheAlpha I don't know, I assume OP wants to get `/` for some reason. Maybe he wants to display the path or something.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: Thanks. I am from a WordPress background. I was using the function to get the media file url. It works using asset() function.