# Post Image to localbitcoin contact

Tags: php, laravel, curl, cryptography

I am trying to post an image (attachment) and message from local database to localbitcoins trade chat, but it is returning me an error. Yes, API keys are valid and working with other methods.

```
{"error": {"message": "HMAC authentication key and signature was given, but they are invalid.", "error_code": 41}}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone please tell me?

```
    $path = '/api/contact_message_post/'.$contact_id."/";    
    
    $key= $this->API_AUTH_KEY;
    $secret= $this->API_AUTH_SECRET;      
 
    $array_mt = explode(' ', microtime());   
    $nonce = $array_mt[1].substr($array_mt[0], 2, 6);   
 
    $post = "";
    if ($req) {
       $post=http_build_query($req);
    }
    $postdata=$nonce.$key.$path.$post; 
 
    $sign = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $postdata, $secret)); 
   
    $headers = array(
       'Apiauth-Signature:'.$sign,
       'Apiauth-Key:'.$key,
       'Apiauth-Nonce:'.$nonce,
       'Content-type: multipart/form-data'
    );

    $ch = null;
    $ch = curl_init('https://localbitcoins.com'.$path); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    dd($res);
    if ($res === false) throw new \Exception('Curl error: '.curl_error($ch));
    $dec = json_decode($res, true);   
    if (!$dec) throw new \Exception('Invalid data: '.$res);
    curl_close($ch);   
    return $dec;
```

I'm trying to add attachment to post data like this.

```
$data = array(
            'document' => new \CURLFile(
                $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\attachments\\'.$attachment, 
                'image/jpeg',
                $attachment
            ),
            'msg' => $messages[0]->message,
        );
```

Comment: here `'content-type: mulitpart/form-data'` multipart it should be, also try to write C as capital in content

Comment: Yeah I fixed that, but again same issue.

Comment: whats inside `$req`

Comment: I guess your attachment file seems wrong to me , this is a example of Curlfile from php docs `// Create a CURLFile object / procedural method
$cfile = curl_file_create('resource/test.png','image/png','testpic'); // try adding

// Create a CURLFile object / oop method
#$cfile = new \CURLFile('resource/test.png','image/png','testpic'); // uncomment and use if the upper procedural method is not working.`

Comment: I'm trying to send data array like this:
`$data = array( 'document' => new \CURLFile( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\attachments\\'.$attachment, 'image/jpeg', $attachment),
 'msg' => $messages[0]->message,);`

Comment: and the attachment file is like this. 
`CURLFile {#1349 ▼
  +name: "C:\xampp\htdocs\BTC dealer\System\public\attachments\1605570383.jpeg"
  +mime: "image/jpeg"
  +postname: "1605570383.jpeg"
}`

Comment: I have not used windows for long time, but are you sure you should use backslash, I think you should use slashes the image I guess is not accessible , see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289384/public-path-returning-results-with-backslash-instead-of-forward-slash

Comment: Yeah it's returning the image there's no problem in that.

Comment: if at the end curl doesn't work out for you, you can use guzzlehttp comes by default with laravel, see this answer if you plan to use guzzle to send images,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559380/laravel-i-received-song-file-form-data-from-one-of-api-then-i-need-to-forwar/63573473#63573473

Comment: last try you can do is pass `$req` instead of `$post` in here `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);`, though I am not sure how it will affect

Comment: Let me check guzzlehttp, I've tried sending poth $post/$req and error is same in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Guzzle and have tried a lot of ways. All other methods work, but only when sending an image, a signature error. I think this is a problem on the Localbitcoins side and we should contact support.

My code: https://gist.github.com/021-code/4026086ab55735744fa8784375046d7d